# trying to find the solution of lasso regression estimate of the given problem

Tags: self-study

I have a question about my Cross Validated post: [NUMERICAL PROBLEM OF LASSO ESTIMATE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525377/numerical-problem-of-lasso-estimate)

[image]

Comment: What is your question about it?

Comment: i cant solve it by hand, like ridge regression we have:  beta(ridge) = inv(X'*X+ lamda*(I))*X'*Y where X' is transpose of data given matrix. how can i solve the above question mentioned in the image for lasso optimal estimate. ?

Comment: Please stop re-posting this question. Instead, follow the directions that I left on your original post.